# Using SOAP with C#, is it possible to return all currently active shipping methods?

Tags: soap

I'm attempting integrating Magento with our backend software and I'm attempting to link up the backend shipping methods with that provided by Magento.

I've had a look at the SOAP api and cannot see a method for returning all currently active shipping methods, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> cart_shipping.list

is the method i think you are looking for

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl'); 

$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_shipping.list', 10);   


var_dump($result);
```

sessionId = The Session Id

quoteId = The autoincremented id of the cart whenever a new order is placed

store = Store View ID

Use this [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.list.html) to get the store data

This will retrieve all shipping methods

Refer to this [Magento Api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.list.html)

Comment: I'd seen this method previously but was unsure what the 'QuoteId' property is? The example provided in the document you linked doesn't appear to reference it.

`($proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10); `

Comment: So you are basically stuck trying to get the quote ID?

Comment: I'm unsure what a quoteId would be. I'm simply trying to return active shipping methods, why are these linked to a shopping cart? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this will help

Comment: I think you've confused my question. I'm not wanting to get the shipping information at the point an order is place. I'm wanting an API method that allows me to simply return all shipping information, not at the point of a sale. Just the data that's been set-up inside of magento.

Comment: In that case the 'cart_shipping.list' is the thing you need in the documentation you can see it 'Allows you to retrieve the list of available shipping methods for a shopping cart (quote).'

Comment: I don't have a shopping cart though, I don't want to get shipping methods for a specific shopping cart. I just want to return all available shipping methods.

I'm basically wanting to dump the list of available shipping methods into a DB which our backend software can access and use them to help configure the shipping methods already setup in the back end.